# Android AVD crashes

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I created a default AVD for Android 2.2 API Level 8, 16Mb card, resolution 640 x 640. It loads with a "locked" appearence, on unlocking it loops on the error message "The Application Launcher has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again"

I'm using Java SDK 1.7 - maybe I should use 1.6?

Any suggestions how to fix this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android does not officially support Java 7, though that unlikely to be your problem in this case.

I would recommend choosing a normal screen resolution and see if that helps. I am not aware of any production devices with 640x640 resolution.

Comment: @SirHowy: There is probably a bug in the Launcher code that can't handle radically different screen resolutions (or perhaps just aspect ratios).